# Add another search field in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that works perfectly

But the need arose, to add another field to the research, I do not know how to solve. It has a checkbox in the form, if it is filled, it fetches the data true in the table, if not the data false, how to add in the code below? I'm in doubt, if at all possible.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, filtro;
  input = document.getElementById("busca2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("tablepesquisa2");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  filtro = document.getElementById("filtroPesquisa2").value;

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[filtro];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <select id="filtroPesquisa2" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">Código</option>
      <option value="1">Descrição</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="text" id="busca2" placeholder="Pesquisa.." onkeyup="myFunction2();" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="table-overflow col-sm-12">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="tablepesquisa2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Código</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Produto) {
        <tr>
          <td>@item.Codigo</td>
          <td>@item.nome</td>
          <td align="right">
            <a href="#" onclick="fecha2();CarregaProduto('@item.Codigo');" title="Selecionar"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        }

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:left;">
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="Produtos" name="Produtos" id="Produtos"/>
<label asp-for="Produtos" class="control-label"></label>
<span asp-validation-for="Produtos" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:left;">
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="Servico" name="Servico" id="Servico"/>
<label asp-for="Servico" class="control-label"></label>
<span asp-validation-for="Servico" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

In this table, have these two fields, then need to be filtered if they are marked or not, if product is marked, have to bring only the fields where product = true, and if it is the other, only the fields that the other is true

**EDIT**
I managed to solve, just by selecting the correct column and comparing to `true`

Comment: Please update the HTML in the snippet I made with 2 or 3 actual examples instead of the template you are using. It is not clear what you want to add either

Comment: This is a modal that I have, when the user marks the checkbox I want him to search in this modal the table data where the checkbox is marked as true.

Comment: Please update the snippet, then explain expected and actual outcome

Comment: I need this filter to be done by jquery, the same is being the others, when marking, perform the filter, only hiding and not on select

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, sorry

Comment: @mplungjan In this example it filters as you type in the textbox, with the option of the select field, however I need to add another filter if the field is checked. Sorry if I do not know how to explain.

Comment: So please add the html I asked and explain expected behaviour with or without checkbox checked

Comment: So please add the html I asked and explain expected behaviour with or without checkbox checked

Comment: @mplungjan editei a pergunta.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50183/72989 In this style, however, I am not able to adapt in my code.

Comment: I do not undertand. The posted link is does not have HTML that can replace `@foreach (var item in Model.Produto) {
        <tr>
          <td>@item.Codigo</td>
          <td>@item.nome</td>
          <td align="right">
            <a href="#" onclick="fecha2();CarregaProduto('@item.Codigo');" title="Selecionar"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
        }` with a proper example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this way:

```
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[filtro];
        td1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
        td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
        var tbBoolean = ($(td2).text() == "True" ? true : false);
        if ($('#Venda').prop("checked") == true) {
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && $(td1).text() == idEmpresa || $(td1).text() == "") {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && tbBoolean == false) {
                    if ($(td1).text() == idEmpresa || $(td1).text() == "") {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    }
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```